# Adding a Identity Authentication in an EXISTING Blazor project and a SEPARATE WebApi project

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, blazor

I am a beginner, and I chose to learn Blazor and WebApi by **NOT** using the Blazor WebAssembly App with ASP.NET Core hosted (*I know I could have just used the template where there is a Client, Server, and Shared projects, but I feel that I can learn better when I understand how they operate separately*). Anyway, instead I did the following:

1. Created an **empty** Solution
2. Added a **Server.WebApi** project using an *ASP.NET Core Web Application (API)* - this is where I placed all my **WebApi Controllers**
3. Added a **Lib.DataAccess** project using a *Class Library (.NET Standard) Targeting Framework 2.1* - this is where I placed my **ApplicationDbContext.cs** and **Migrations** Folder
4. Added a **Lib.Entities** project using a *Class Library (.NET Standard) Targeting Framework 2.1* - this is where I placed my **Models** and **ViewModels**
5. Added a **Client.Blazor** project using a *Blazor Web Assembly App* but not ASP.NET Core hosted, and with *No Authentication*

So far, I was able to make everything work properly.

But now, I'd like to learn how to **Add Identity Authentication** in my existing solution...but I don't know how or where to begin...because I also don't really understand the concepts behind or how it works..

Inquiries:

1. Can somebody please help add this to my existing project? Do I install packages on Client.Blazor and Server.WebApi? or install in Server.WebApi only?
2. Can I use a separate DbContext and separate Database Schema for the Identity Authentication? Or is it proper to use a different DbContext but use the same Database Schema?
3. In relation to #2, I do not know how to implement either...
4. When I implement Identity Authentication, is there a way for me to select User Roles (*such as System Admin, Encoder, Guest, etc...*)?
5. When a user is logged in (*I'm kinda assuming that the user account logged in data is in the Server.WebApi*), is it possible for me to retrieve user account data in the Client.Blazor project?

I apologize for asking too much here, but there's just too much information in the internet and I am kind of getting lost already...Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You may want to start here: https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/ this should get you started adding the authentication part. If you want to ensure your web api is secure, best to start looking into Jwt bearer tokens - if you're using http client, the token can be passed in the client header upon each request and allow you to use the Authorize attribute on your controllers.

Comment: @ChrisCampbell thank you thank you very much! After reading the article, this is EXACLTY the kind of article I'm looking for!!! Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @ChrisCampbell this helped me too, thanks